# Angular, NULL from a get request. Server HTTP REST

Tags: angular, rest, http, ionic-framework, get

I'm stuck with this small piece of code. I'm working with login, so I'm currently using a GET to obtain an answer from the server if the data is correct. Example: if the username and password match, it will send a message saying that login succeeded, otherwise it was not. I'm always getting a NULL value. I already tried one billion different ways and it still doesn't work.

```
    verifyPessoa(){ 
 this.http.get(`http://URL/${this.pessoaDetails.user}/${this.pessoaDetails.senha}`)
      .subscribe((res : Response) =>{
          console.log(JSON.stringify(res));           
          debugger;     
    }
```

`console.log()`, just print "null".
Any suggestions will help me a lot. I'm just starting with angular too.
***UPDATE***
It was *CORS* problem related on the server side.

Comment: what does the network tab show ?

Comment: did you try checking if the problem is in the API?, try by checking directly the API in the browser, becasue if you are getting null is because the API is returning null

Comment: Are you sure, that the address is valid and your app can connect to the server ? No HTTP error will be returned if your app can't connect to the server in the first place.

Comment: The API is right, because i can see the entries on the server as i press the button... It's really weird because i can see the User and Password that i'm sending to the server on the server but it returns null...

Comment: I tried so many ways already.. Don't really know what to do

Comment: Yes, i can acess it from the browser. Don't really know what is going on.

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED! It was a CORS settings on the server side!